# Caesar Cipher shifting characters

Tags: c, arrays, string, encryption

I had received this assignment last month and ended up getting it wrong because of the problem I will state after this. Currently, I am doing Caesar's Cipher and I believe I have the right format. I ask the user for a string and I encrypted with a `key == 3`. However, I want to loop around the alphabet if the plaintext letter is `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `x`, `y`, or `z`. But, when I put those any of those characters in, I do not get `A`, `B`, and `C`, but `]...` and other braces. Any hints to fix the problem. 
Thank you!

```
void main()
{    
    int key = 3;

    char string[256];
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter the string you want encrypted\n");
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        if (string[i] == ' ') {;}

        else if  ((string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z' || string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z')){
                string[i] = string[i] + key;
        }
    }
    printf("Cipher text:%s",string);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at the ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/. You're using an ASCII encoding of the characters.

Z has a decimal value of 90, so 93 is ']'. You need to manually wrap back around to the beginning of the alphabet. This is best done with a modulo and adding the ASCII value of the first alphabetic character. It's up to you how you wrap capital letters (back to 'a' or to 'A').

Comment: So basically mod% 26 and adding the first letter 'a' ?

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the character to its position in the alphabet, then find the result modulo 26 (alphabet length), then convert it back to the character. Something like:

```
char base = 0;
if(string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z'){
    base = 'a';
}else if(string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z'){
    base = 'A';
}
if(base){
    string[i] = ((string[i] - base) + key) % 26 + base;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char string[256];
    int i = 0;
    int key = 3;
    const int num_letters = 26;

    printf("Enter the string you want encrypted\n");
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        if (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z') {
            string[i] = 'a' + (string[i] - 'a' + key) % num_letters;
        }
        else if (string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z') {
            string[i] = 'A' + (string[i] - 'A' + key) % num_letters;
        }
    }
    printf("Encrypted: %s\n", string);
    return 0;
}

Enter the string you want encrypted
Zorro
Encrypted: Cruur
```

In C you can use the modulo operator `%` to wrap around, as shown above. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks ! Understood well!